# Java debugging between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging

In the following code (from server thread) I have a debugger break point (marked).

```
public void run () {


    ServerSocket server;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket (3150);

        int i = 0;
        GameStartNotifier notifGame = new GameStartNotifier (this);
        notifGame.start ();
        while (not_started2 == true) {
            try {


                assert server != null;
                ClientConnection conn = new ClientConnection (server.accept (), this, i);
                conn.start (); //breakpoint---
                host.arr.add (conn);
```

Also in ClientConnection thread:

```
public void run(){
String name = in.readLine (); // breakpoint----(in is a BufferedReader wrapping an InputStream obj on 
//a socket input stream)
```

However both breakpoints are never reached! (Even though a Clientconnection obj is created).
TIA

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. At least: tell us what IDE, debugger, ... you are using. Beyond that: have you tried setting breakpoints in other (earlier) lines of your code, and did that work?

Comment: Intellij. All worked in both threads including clientconnection constructor

Comment: Please dont put such information into comments, always update your question instead. But again, we most likely cant help with the amount of information you have provided so far. Please read that link I gave you carefully, and then try to add those things to your question that we need to understand what exactly you are doing.